# Weird POSIXct error

Tags: r, posixct

For some reason, `as.POSIXct` interprets `"2013-03-10 02:00:00.000"` different from other valid datetimes in that format.

```
> as.POSIXct("2013-03-10 01:00:00.000") #Different time, same date
[1] "2013-03-10 01:00:00 PST"

> as.POSIXct("2013-03-11 02:00:00.000") #Same time, different date
[1] "2013-03-11 02:00:00 PDT"

> as.POSIXct("2013-03-10 02:00:00.000")
[1] "2013-03-10 PST"
```

I'm using the package `RODBC` to read this from a database, and it automatically converts this entire column of datetimes into `POSIXct` class. This causes the entire column to lose time information.

Comment: Daylight savings time shift???  Does 2 AM on 2013-03-10 not exist in that time zone?

Comment: @BenBolker is right.  2 AM didn't exist on that date.

Comment: Of course - that would explain the shift from PST to PDT. I suppose there's no easy way around this without altering the code of the `RODBC` package or changing the values in the database?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich , feel free to edit my answer.  @Señor O, I don't know whether `RODBC` has the equivalent of a `colClasses` argument so that you could force the column to be read in as character, then mess with it as you saw fit once you had it in R.

Comment: Looks like it has an `as.is` argument to keep a column as a character vector. I agree it's odd that `as.POSIXct` doesn't give a warning or return `NA`, and especially that it erases the time information on the entire column as a result of one odd value.

Comment: @SeñorO: What timezone are the values in the database stored in? Perhaps they're GMT (or another timezone that doesn't have DST)? I wouldn't recommend changing data unless you're 100% certain it's wrong.

Comment: That's a good question. I would think GMT since the reported times are from all around the world. I can't change the `tz` argument without changing the source code for RODBC. The default `tz` is `Sys.timezone()`, which has a call to `Sys.time` and therefore `.Internal`, so I'd rather not mess with that.

Comment: @SeñorO: that's easily fixed via `Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")`.

Comment: or `Sys.setenv(TZ='PST')` in OP's case.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: no, the OP thinks the data in the DB is in GMT though his machine is PST; and you can't set the timezone in the RODBC call, so you can get around that issue by setting R's timezone to GMT.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich whoops, should've read more carefully.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich wouldn't it be better to use UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a daylight savings time issue: apparently 2 AM on 2013-03-10 doesn't exist in that time zone. Nevertheless, it's mildly interesting (at least to me) that `as.POSIXct` doesn't complain, but silently returns a slightly odd answer. One problem may be that R typically uses system libraries for some of this stuff, and so is at the whim of the underlying libraries ...

*Incorporating useful information from the comments*: @JoshUlrich points out that you can get around this (provided that the original data are really in GMT) by using `Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")` before importing the data, since `RODBC` uses the system-level timezone rather than allowing you to specify it ...

Comment: ...but I get the same behavior on Win32 (R-2.15.2) and Ubuntu 64 (R-3.0.1).  I swear this used to return `NA`.

Comment: Daylight savings was the issue, and `Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")` was an easy workaround.